# Ethernet disconnects after a few minutes

Tags: ethernet

After upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 my Ethernet disconnects after a few minutes.

I tried to set IPv6 Method to Ignore or raise MTU to 8192, but the <kbd>Save</kbd> button is grey, not black, and I cannot save the new settings.

Comment: Why such high MTU? when it's running for few min but before it disconnects post your `ifconfig -a` most likely at hardware issue, bad cable, bad port etc... try swapping a cable and plugging in different port on switch if you can

Comment: I do not thing this is a cable issue, because if I click network and Wired connection 1 then I see a message "disconnected" and then "connection reestablisdhed" and my network connection works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try some of these.
If you need to find out which packages were updated, in Synaptic package manager Click file > history. Search for the date of your last update, then click the plus sign next to it. When it opens, click the label with your month, day, year.
This will tell you, what updates you had made, and there is a screenshot that will show you how it look like. You have now a list of your updates to help you troubleshoot the problem. You can either remove them through Synaptic or the terminal, or reinstall old versions using command like:
`sudo dpkg -i "packagename"`
So Your command should look like for eg:
`sudo dpkg -i evolution-common_2.48.1-0ubuntu16.04`
Good luck.